# What was the purpose of the Java Virtual Machine to run java on architectures when porting the JVM was necessary anyway?

Tags: java, jvm, porting

I'm trying to analyze the nature of porting and virtual machines, with the intent of minimizing the amount of porting.

Looking back into the history of things, one thing stands out in my mind, however. The Java Virtual Machine, i.e. SDK/JRE, though it is able to dynamically process java classes and/or compile java source code, is essentially middleware, is it not? I imagine the people at Oracle recompile it for different operating systems in order for the Java language to be of use to each respective operating system.

So, all this brings me to my above stated question, "Why institute a Java Virtual Machine when Java itself could exist as yet another language and be ported to different architectures without the need for porting the middleware (i.e. the middleware in this case being the JVM)?"

This is just an assumption, but would it be because the JVM is designed to have minimal porting requirements among architectures, and thus modification of existing java between architectures requires less work?
Thanks.

Comment: Because the JVM only need be ported once to each supported platform versus every piece of software written in Java needing to maintain different versions for each platform. It's all pros and cons - Java is a garbage collected language that runs on a virtual machine, so there's a fair bit of overhead and will run slower than clean code written in C/C++, but the pro is no need for memory management and no need to manage multiple codebases.

Comment: I see, so technically it can be presupposed that there is a need for a similar "vm/garbage collector" for c/c++ for eliminating the need for memory management and managing multiple codebases for those languages as well?

Comment: Well yes ... but the C/C++ languages are designed in such a way that garbage collection is problematic.  For example, if an application can perform arithmetic on pointers, it is difficult for the GC to know *reliably* when the applications variables are referring to real heap objects.

Comment: Middleware is an ill-defined term.  So if you assert that the JVM is middleware, the next question is going to be "what do you mean by middleware".

Comment: It's a lot easier to port an interpreter than a compiler. It's really as simple as that.

Comment: I disagree with that (a bit).  But that's just my opinion. And that's the problem with this Question.  It is all a matter of opinion.

Comment: @BigSum You would make a lot of people very angry if you implemented garbage collection in C++ - it would be impossible to write AAA games or anything with high-end graphics in a garbage collected language. It depends what you're doing, if you're just making some light app/software then Java's perfectly fine and will greatly reduce a lot of problems like memory leaks, but if you really need high performance then you'll probably have to go for a lower-level language like C/C++.

Comment: @Stephen C In the same way firmware allows interoperability between hardware and operating system software, this is what I mean by a sort of "middleware". Or in the same sense, how the operating system acts as "middleware" between the hardware and the user application.

Comment: @StephenC Disagree why? If that wasn't the case the JVM wouldn't exist. Have you ever ported either?

Comment: @user207421 - Don't encourage the OP to post questions that encourage discussion. (For the record, I disagree with your assertion that "it is simple as that". There are other factors / reasons as well.)

Comment: @BigSum - A question that ends up being "answered" in comments ... and then placed on hold / deleted ... is not a good question.   Anyway, if you believe that you have got your answer, you should now delete the question.

Comment: @Stephen C I believe deleting my question would obscure the notion as to why the JVM is important for java, and for garbage collected languages in general. So, no, I stand by the rectification of knowledge.

Comment: @BigSum _"I believe deleting my question would obscure the notion as to why the JVM is important for java"_ With all due respect: this is a negative-score question self-answered by a very low rep user. Keeping it or deleting it will have exactly zero effect on the notion of anything. (Again, with all due respect.)

Comment: @walen Oh well, I'll try if I can keep it and see what happens. I try to be optimistic. Anyways, thanks everyone for all the input. My rep is low, I know. I'm not on much.

Answer (score -1):

Pros and cons prevail with regard as to when such software as Java's Virtual Machine is used instead of just implementing a language each time there is a need on a different architecture. As commenters above have posed, porting compilers to new architectures to compile a language's code, let's say, Java's without its Virtual Machine, would comprise much more industrious tasks than porting over a single piece of software designed not to change much over time and handle execution and memory management, among things, for a widely-used language, say, like the existing one we have with Java. Thus, the Virtual Machine provided alongside Java is a pro in this regard with its reduction in the amount of refactoring required.

However, perhaps the most visible con is that virtual machines running the language would render applications using the language slow access to the hardware underlying the virtual machine, due to the internal garbage collection mechanisms and built-in memory management which together would result in significant overhead. Hence, high performance applications such as AAA games would be ruled out and/or severely impeded.

Comment: There is no need for the repetition of the old “Java is slow” myth.

Comment: @Holger If you think that there are certain aspects of Java which outweigh the overhead of a JVM, please feel free to answer and/or contribute.